# VSTS Online can't clone large repo via ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops

When trying to clone a large repo from VSTS Online I get the following error after about 1% of it has cloned:

```
remote: Found 24565 objects to send. (83 ms)        
Receiving objects:   0% (1/24565)   
Receiving objects:   1% (246/24565)   
Connection reset by 104.43.203.175 port 22
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Smaller repos work fine via ssh, unless I don't specify the --depth 1 option, like somehow it doesn't want to give me too much data.

Cloning via https works fine though...

Comment: It's saying the remote server disconnected early. You would probably have to troubleshoot this on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can config the compression as `0` for your local git repo configuration:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Then try to clone with ssh (I cloned 400MB size repo successful after changing compression as `0`).

Comment: How big does your repo?

Comment: About 400 megabytes... It mysteriously started working just fine now, even without the core.compression flag so I dunno, maybe something going wrong with vsts?

Comment: It's mainly not. The cloned issue is mainly caused by the size of the git repo and the time consumed during `git clone`. If git clone takes a bit longer time, git command may run out of memory.